# window.URL is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, fileapi

I have an array being populated with blobs (it works correctly) and I want to convert the *Blob* to *Image* as soon as I get the blob.

```
(function(index) {

    images[index] = new Image();

    xhr.onload = function() {

        blobs[index] = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'image/png'});

        console.log(index + " loaded.");
        console.log(blobs[index]); // It works as expected.

        (function(b) {

            var img = window.URL.createObjectURL(b); // window.URL is undefined.
            console.log(img); // Failed.

        })(blobs[index]);

    };

})(i);
```

The anonymous function is not called immediately after the `console.log`, and it throws the error:

> TypeError: window.URL is undefined

I'm using Firefox 17, which already features **window.URL**, so that's not the problem. Actually, I can use window.URL outside this function.

**EDIT:** I had a global scope variable called URL without value, so window.URL referred to it. (Can't self-answer due to my low reputation)

Comment: try wrapping it on an onload handler maybe the window object is not yet ready when your function fires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a global scope variable called URL without value, so window.URL referred to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you should check the value of your parameter `b` to ensure it indeed does have value. Sounds to me that it does not and therefore will cause `window.URL` to be undefined during construction.

It doesn't sound like you are new to this so I won't sit here and tell you how to debug that but I think that is the best place to look, from what I can see here your code looks as to be expected.

**Note:**
What Mark Dee said is very well a valid option as well, you should make sure that the Document is ready and then try your function see if this helps.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //CODE HERE
});
```

Old JavaScript

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    //CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing that if I enter `if (window.URL) console.log(true);` it returns _undefined_ in my site, but _true_ in any other site.

Comment: What do you refer to site as? Separate domain?

Comment: Ahh. I see. Yeah that'll do it. Thanks for the followup.